# Symfony4 redirecting all users who not have admin role using kernel.exception

Tags: php, exception, symfony4

i want to redirect all users who not have the role of admin to home page with kernel.exception

**this is my Controller page :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\IsGranted;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class ProduitController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/produit", name="produit")
     * @IsGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('produit/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

**this is EventListener:**

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

class NotAuthenticationListener
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();

        if (!$exception instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
            return;
        }
        return new Response("Access Denied !");
    }
}
```

**service.yaml**

```
App\EventListener\NotAuthenticationListener:
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

> but it's not working
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uajV4.png)

Answer (score 0):

I always *love* to cite documentation. In this case [GetResponseForExceptionEvent](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.2/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Event/GetResponseForExceptionEvent.php):

```
 /**
 * Allows to create a response for a thrown exception.
 *
 * Call setResponse() to set the response that will be returned for the
 * current request. The propagation of this event is stopped as soon as a
 * response is set.
 *
 * You can also call setException() to replace the thrown exception. This
 * exception will be thrown if no response is set during processing of this
 * event.
 *
 * @author Bernhard Schussek <bschussek@gmail.com>
 */
```

so essentially: returning something in an EventListener is just ... useless. you have to call `setResponse` on the event and set your response that way.

Hope that helps ;o)